# How to submit data with a POST request synchronously, i.e. not an ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to send some custom object in a POST request but synchronously, i.e. I want the browser to refresh and load the new target page, and I do not want to make an ajax request.

In other words, I'd like to submit a form with some custom data object made out of the values of its fields. How would I do that?

```
function postData()
{
  var person = { FirstName: "John", LastName: "Doe" };

  // How do I send the person object as a part of the POST data
  $("#myForm").submit();
}
```

Comment: Maybe try to add hidden fields to form. This fields will represent person object.

Comment: @robertw Thank you. Looks like I am going to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the form on the fly:

```
var myForm = $('<form>', { method: 'POST', target: 'YOUR_TARGET' } ); // create a new form
myForm.append($('<input>', { name: 'FirstName', value: 'John' }));
myForm.append($('<input>', { name: 'LastName', value: 'Doe' }));
myForm.hide().appendTo('body');
myForm.submit()
```

However, in case you just want to add custom data to an existing form, you can do this instead

```
var myForm = $('#myForm');
myForm.append($('<input>', { type: 'hidden', name: 'FirstName', value: 'John' }));
myForm.submit()
```

Comment: Thank you. I already have a form, so I guess I am going to just add the missing fields as hidden ones and submit it.

Comment: Thank you. I understood that I could do that from your original answer. I was just waiting the 6 minutes you have to wait before you can mark an answer.